# IIS W3C Log files missing header

Tags: iis-7, log-files

I've just gotten around to analyzing our log files.  After banging my head with log parser and several other 'analyzer' tools I came to realize that my log files appear to be missing their header section. There are no #Software, #Version, #Date nor #Fields directives - it just starts right into the log data.
I've looked closely at the IIS logging dialog and don't see a bool there to 'enable header' or anything...

I'm using Windows Server 2008 (x64) running IIS version 7.0.6000.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the log file format has been set to `W3C` and not `IIS` or `NCSA`. In both of those instances, the log files have no header.

If your log files are in W3C format, the log filenames will begin with `u_ex` by default. For IIS format the prefix is `u_in` and for NCSA the prefix is `u_nc`

[image: IIS Log file Configuration]

Comment: I was viewing the logging settings of the IIS root value (machine) - when I then selected the "Default Web Site" entry - I discovered entirely different logging settings.  My log files are prefixed with u_nc. Thanks!